# JPA 1.0 Entity class mapping improvements

Tags: performance, jakarta-ee, jpa, websphere

All,
We have 300 entity classes that was generated from existing DB schema for a J2EE web application.
We are facing performance issues in one of the application sections and wanted to know if:

> 1. It’s possible to tune/optimize the current mappings (@ManyToOne,
>      @OneToMany) relationsships to make the runtime less heavy? If so, how
>      and what would be a starting point.
> 2. Is there a tool(s) that mark out the improvements in such entity
>      classes?
> 3. Will such improvements/changes impact the DB structure. We would
>      like to keep the DB structure impact?

Please note that the application is not in production yet. We do not want/avoid to change the current DB structure.

System info:
Windows XP
IBM Websphere AS 7.0.0.15
RAD 7.5
Hibernate 3.3
Spring 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It’s possible to tune/optimize the current mappings (@ManyToOne,
>   @OneToMany) relationsships to make the runtime less heavy? If so, how
>   and what would be a starting point.

Yes, to start with investigating lazy loading of relationships and fetch groups so that you are not pulling your whole object graph back from the db, but rather just the objects & fields you need.

> Is there a tool(s) that mark out the improvements in such entity
>   classes?

None that I know of. You really have to be aware of your domain and how your application is using it.

> Will such improvements/changes impact the DB structure. We would like
>   to keep the DB structure impact?

Changing how hibernate fetches your objects should not alter your structure in your database at all.